# Excel, convert a number with k 100k to its value 100000

Tags: excel

I have an Excel table containing values like this:

```
3.30k
41.30k
42.31
```

I would like to get the real numeric value like this:

```
3300
41300
42.31
```

Is that possible?

Note the formula bar when i click a cell contains "3k" for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `Column A` is not formatted as numbers, try

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("k",A1)),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*IF(RIGHT(A1)="k",1000,1),A1)
```

[image]

Comment: it removes the last number if it doesn't contain k, example 1.7 gets converted to 1.0

Comment: @giò - Oops! use `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("k",A1)),LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="k",1000,1),A1)`

Comment: ok working now, you may want to remove the first formula to avoid confusion

Comment: @Mrig as Scott Craner pointed out once upon a time.  If you are only stripping 1 character with the LEFT or RIGHT function, the default value is 1 so RIGHT(A1) is the same as RIGHT(A1,1).

Comment: @ForwardEd - Thanks for sharing that, never heard of it before, answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("k",A1),1,"")*1000
```

Change A1 to suit your cell

Or
assuming you may also use m for millions, or no letter if less than 1000

you could use

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(REPLACE(A1,FIND("k",A1),1,"")*1000,REPLACE(A1,FIND("m",A1),1,"")*1000000),A1)
```

Comment: sorry, I did it but nothing changed

Comment: @giò click in a cell, what is in the formula bar? The full value or 3k etc

Comment: The bar displays 3k as I wrote in the original post, I would like to convert that to the numeric values without k

Comment: that's better, but consider that not every number has k, you must take in account both (1.7 and 3.4k)

Comment: @giò again edited to include m for millions, would you use b for billions also ?

Answer (score 2):

one more formula option:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"k","")*IF(RIGHT(A1)="k",1000,1)
```

A1 refers to your source cell.  Place the above formula in in empty cell and copy down or right to suit your data.

Apparently this is case sensitive, so to cover both cases you could use:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"k",""),"K","")*IF(RIGHT(A1)="k",1000,1)
```

[image: poc]