# Format (36.4K) as -36400, 1.0k as 1000

Tags: excel, excel-formula, number-formatting

[image]I have downloaded data from tableau and once I try to work on this on Excel I get some weird format for the numbers.
I have the values on the left, and on the right side I typed what should they actually display.
Can I get some help? I tried some formulas but they do not account for the empty spot.
This question is different from other as a similar question does not account for the blank spot.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel, convert a number with k 100k to its value 100000](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46405456/11683)

Comment: No, because it does not account for the empty spots. I tried playing around with it and it does not take me closer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert 1k to 1000 and 1m to 1000000 in Excel](https://superuser.com/q/1459247/52365)

Comment: What does *account for the empty spots* mean? Zero is correct for your first row.

Comment: @AlfredoHuerta Wrapping the provided formula with an `if(isblank(A1),0, ...)` is the easiest thing.

Comment: A formula like this??  =if(isblank(K2),0, SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(k2"k",""),"K","")*IF(RIGHT(k2)="k",1000,1))

Comment: It does not work because it does not distinguish the parenthesis, instead of giving value -36400, it gives -36.4

Comment: This question should not have been closed because, as the OP pointed out, the linked question doesn't account for negative values with parethesis formatting.

Comment: How can if(isblank(C192),0..... to this formula   =SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(C192),"K","")*IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("K",C192)),1000,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need, tested on the sample data you gave

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("K",A1)),VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"K",""))*1000,A1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you just saved my job at this internship. Would you mind explaining the formula. I am kind of new to this.

Comment: First you remove the Ks, if there are any, with `SUBSTITUTE` and then `VALUE` evaluates the input and returns the corresponding numeric value, so _(500)_ becomes _-500_. Finally, if you did remove a K you need to multiply this output by 1000, if not you just leave it as is